# SAS, PROC SOAP, windows, java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: web-services, soap, sas, proc

I am trying to download an XML file from a Dutch government website. I’m hoping to find some help here as [1] (surprise, surprise) the government organization does not provide support for the use of the web service they provide and [2] I cannot find anything on the error messages that I am getting.
java.net.UnknownHostException:
Does anybody have an idea as to what the cause of this error could be and perhaps how to resolve it?

I have a valid UID and PW with which I can log in on the site and manually download the 4-5GB XML file.
I am using the code below. The SOAP Envelope in the DATA _NULL and the URL used in the PROC  were cut & pasted from the webservice’s documentation and, in the case of the envelope message, adapted for UID and PW.

```html
OPTIONS MPRINT MLOGIC SYMBOLGEN;
FILENAME request  "&DATROOT\REQUEST.xml";
FILENAME response  "&DATROOT\Response.xml";

DATA _NULL_;
 FILE request;
 INPUT;
 PUT _INFILE_;
 DATALINES4;
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:epb="..."
 xmlns:epb1="...">
  <soapenv:Header>
   <epb:EpbdDownloadMutationFileHeader>
   <epb:username>xxxxxx</epb:username>
   <epb:password>XXXXXXXXXXX</epb:password>
   </epb:EpbdDownloadMutationFileHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <epb1:DownloadMutationFile>
   <epb1:request>
   <epb1:mutationType>Complete</epb1:mutationType>
   </epb1:request>
   </epb1:DownloadMutationFile>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
;;;;
RUN;

%LET RESPONSE=RESPONSE;
PROC SOAP IN=request
 OUT=&RESPONSE
 URL="https://webapplicaties.agro.nl/DownloadMutationFile/EpbdDownloadMutationFile.asmx" 
  wssusername="xxxxxx"
  wsspassword="XXXXXXXXXXX";
RUN;
```

The resulting Log reads:

```html
24         PROC SOAP IN=request
25          OUT=&RESPONSE
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESPONSE resolves to RESPONSE
26          URL="https://webapplicaties.agro.nl/DownloadMutationFile/EpbdDownloadMutationFile.asmx"
27           wssusername="xxxxxx"
28           wsspassword=XXXXXXXXXXX;
29         RUN;

ERROR: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: webapplicaties.agro.nl; nested exception is 
java.net.UnknownHostException: webapplicaties.agro.nl
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be due to the fact you are behind a proxy server?  Can you access other SOAP services?  There are options (`PROXYHOST`, `PROXYPORT` etc) in `proc soap` you can use, documented [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/a003176692.htm)

I've also found different log results with `proc http`, when running in EG vs Base SAS - which you can experiment with (possibly due to the version of java being used).